# Using an object as column wrapper in a Sequelize model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am in the process of building a REST api on top of an existing database schema using Node, Express, Sequelize and Mssql.

I am not able/allowed to modify the existing database as there is a legacy application relying on its structure with many hardcoded SQL-queries.

I've read through Sequelize's documentation without finding anything about how to define a model to achieve this. Is this possible and if so how can this be done?

#### What i want to return from the api

```
{
    id: 1234,
    title: "abc"
    images: ["img.jpg", "img.jpg", "img.jpg"]
}
```

#### What the table looks like:

```
 +----+-------+----------+----------+----------+
 | id | title |  image_1 |  image_2 |  image_3 |
 +----+-------+----------+----------+----------+
 | 1  | abc   | img1.jpg | img2.jpg | img3.jpg |
 +----+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

#### My incomplete model-definition

```
const News = sequelize.define(
    "news",
    {
        id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        title: Sequelize.TEXT,
        images: ????
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to make the "images" field with getter:

```
images: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
    get() {
        const imageFields = ['image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3'];
        return imageFields.map(this.getDataValue);
    },
}
```

UPD: The method above works for defining inside an existing property.

If you want to make it inside a model try the following:

```
const News = sequelize.define(
    "news",
    { ... },
    {
        getterMethods: {
            name() {
                const imageFields = ['image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3'];
                return imageFields.map(field => this[field]);
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Sequelize assumes that the images property maps to a column named images - even with the custom getter function.
I get the following error message: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid column name 'images'.`

Comment: Please check the updated version. I've added getter definition in a model.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to help me! Your updated suggestion works, but only if the images-fields are present in the model definition. Running news.get() on an instance will have the `images` property, but only if also has the properties `image_1`, `image_2`, `image_3` etc. I can live with that, but it means i'll have to define another getter that only returns the intended properties before i can pass it on as a response or manually extract what is needed at the relevant endpoints, which i find a little strange.

Comment: Since you have `image_1`, `image_2` and `image_3` in your table already, it's enough to define them as the model properties. In my opinion, it's a good practice to reflect all columns in the model.
After you have added `image_#` fields and the `name` getter, `news.get('name')` should work just fine.